# characters are shifted horizontally when using itextpdf java API to generate PDF with large font size

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm trying to generate a PDF containing a grid of letters, where each letter is centered in its cell in the grid (both vertically and horizontally), see attached PDF samples
This works well when the font size I'm using is relatively small (44 in the attached sample) but fails for larger fonts (94 in the attached sample).

- When specifying a minimum width for the cell, the characters are horizontally shifted wrt the cell center (except for the 'I' and 'J' which still fit the cell width, note that the shift varies between letters, most notably 'A' and 'B'). see image below
- When the minimum width is not specified, the characters are centered wrt the cell, but these in turn are wider, causing only part of the row to be displayed. see image below

code:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.DeviceGray;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.DeviceRgb;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.SolidBorder;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.HorizontalAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.OverflowPropertyValue;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.Property;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.VerticalAlignment;

public class PDFWriterTest {
    public static final int DPI = 72;
    public static final float PAGE_WIDTH = 19.685f;
    public static final float PAGE_HEIGHT = 25.5906f;
    public static final float MARGIN = 1.1811f;
    public static final float MATRIX_WIDTH = 72 * (PAGE_WIDTH - 2 * MARGIN);
    public static final float MATRIX_HEIGHT = 72 * (PAGE_HEIGHT - 2 * MARGIN);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final int numColumns = 24;
            final int numRows = 24;
            final List<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();
            final int fontSize44 = 44;
            final int fontSize94 = 94;
            final boolean showGrid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
                    letters.add(getStr(i));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Writing output to: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            final FileOutputStream fOut44 = new FileOutputStream("./pdf_size44.pdf");
            generatePdfDocument(numColumns, numRows, letters, fontSize44, showGrid, false, fOut44);
            final FileOutputStream fOut44min = new FileOutputStream("./pdf_size44_min.pdf");
            generatePdfDocument(numColumns, numRows, letters, fontSize44, showGrid, true, fOut44min);
            final FileOutputStream fOut94 = new FileOutputStream("./pdf_size94.pdf");
            generatePdfDocument(numColumns, numRows, letters, fontSize94, showGrid, false, fOut94);
            final FileOutputStream fOut94min = new FileOutputStream("./pdf_size94_min.pdf");
            generatePdfDocument(numColumns, numRows, letters, fontSize94, showGrid, true, fOut94min);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("PDF generation failed: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
    public static void generatePdfDocument (final int numColumns, final int numRows, final List<String> letters,
                                            final int fontSize, final boolean showGrid, final boolean setMinWidth,
                                            final FileOutputStream fOut) throws Exception {
        final float pageWidth = PAGE_WIDTH * DPI;
        final float pageHeight = PAGE_HEIGHT * DPI;
        try {
            final PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fOut);
            final PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            final PageSize ps = new PageSize(pageWidth, pageHeight);
            final  Document doc = new Document(pdf, ps);
            doc.setMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
            
            final Table maskTable =
                    generateTable(pageWidth, pageHeight, numColumns, numRows, letters, fontSize, showGrid, setMinWidth);
            doc.add(maskTable);
            doc.flush();
            doc.close();
        } finally {
            fOut.close();
        }

    }
    
    public static Table generateTable (final float width, final float height, final int numCols, final int numRows,
                                       final List<String> letters, final int fontSize, final boolean showGrid,
                                       final boolean setMinWidth) {
        final Table mainTable = new Table(1);
        mainTable.setWidth(width);
        mainTable.setHeight(height);
        mainTable.setMargins(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        mainTable.setPadding(0.0f);
        final Cell mainCell = new Cell();
        mainCell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        mainCell.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
        mainCell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
        mainCell.setBackgroundColor(DeviceGray.BLACK);
        
        final Table lettersTable = new Table(numCols);
        lettersTable.setWidth(MATRIX_WIDTH);
        lettersTable.setHeight(MATRIX_HEIGHT);
        lettersTable.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        lettersTable.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        lettersTable.setMargins(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        lettersTable.setPaddingLeft(MARGIN * DPI);
        lettersTable.setPaddingTop(MARGIN * DPI);
        final float cellWidth = MATRIX_WIDTH /((float)numCols) - (showGrid ? 0.2f: 0);
        final float cellHeight = MATRIX_HEIGHT /((float)numRows) - (showGrid ? 0.2f: 0);

        for (final String letter : letters) {
            lettersTable.addCell(generateCell(letter, cellWidth, cellHeight, fontSize, showGrid, setMinWidth));
        }

        mainCell.add(lettersTable);
        mainTable.addCell(mainCell);
        return mainTable;
    }
    private static Cell generateCell (final String cellText, final float cellWidth, final float cellHeight, final int fontSize, final boolean showGrid, boolean setMinWidth) {
        final Cell nextCell = new Cell();

        final Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
                                .setFontColor(DeviceGray.WHITE)
                                .setFontSize(fontSize)
                                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                                .setPaddingLeft(0.0f)
                                .setMargins(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
                                .setCharacterSpacing(0.0f)
                                .setWordSpacing(0.0f)
                                .setFirstLineIndent(0.0f)
                                .setMultipliedLeading(0.1f);
        p.setProperty(Property.OVERFLOW_Y, OverflowPropertyValue.VISIBLE);
        p.setProperty(Property.OVERFLOW_X, OverflowPropertyValue.VISIBLE);
        p.add(cellText);
        nextCell.add(p);
        nextCell.setMargins(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        nextCell.setBorder(showGrid ? new SolidBorder(DeviceRgb.RED, 0.1f) : Border.NO_BORDER);
        nextCell.setWidth(cellWidth);
        if (setMinWidth) {
            nextCell.setMinWidth(cellWidth);
        }
        nextCell.setHeight(cellHeight);
        nextCell.setPadding(0.0f);
        nextCell.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
        nextCell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        return nextCell;
    }

    private static String getStr(int i) {
        final StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
        strB.append((char)(i + 65));
        return strB.toString();
    }
}
```

Generated PDF samples:

[image: font 44 - good]

[image: font 94 with min width - horizontal shift wrt to cell]

[image: font 94 w/o min width - cells are too wide]

Comment: Thanks @KJ! The idea of exporting from HTML sounds interesting.
From your experience - would it make sense to try working with itext canvas API - something like: showTextAligned which seem to support exact X location (which we will have to calculate)
https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.html#showTextAligned-com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte-int-com.itextpdf.text.Phrase-float-float-float-

Comment: thanks @KJ, your inputs are very appreciated.
Indeed version 8 seems to solve our problem, at least partially.
'should' is the keyword here.... As always, the devil is in the details :-)